# get a return from a function in another class

Tags: python

I want to get a return value, which changes the value due to an triggered event.
like so:

```
class A:
      def __init__(self):
        self.ev_nearby = 0

      def changeValue(self):
         self.ev_nearby = 1
         return self.ev_nearby

      # I want this value in class B
      def getChangedValue(self):
         return self.ev_nearby

      def logic(self):
          while(somethingHappens) {
             self.changeValue()
          }
      # logic is called in another class

class B:
      A = A()
      # I want the value here like
      valueFromA = A.getChangedValue()
```

The reason of the while is because I need both values dynamically in a server.
But until now, my valueFromA in class B remains still 0, triggered or not triggered.

Comment: here `class B:
      A = A()
      # I want the value here like
      valueFromA = A.getChangedValue(self)` you don't have to put "self" as argument to A.getChangedValue

and did you execute method to change this value? In example cod I can't find where it's used

Comment: It seems to me that "self" call "A.getChangedValue(self)" is unnecessary.

Comment: oh sorry, I copied the getChangedValue() from above with the self in it. Which method do you mean? @darvark do you mean getChangedValue() ? Isn't it called with A.getChangedValue() ?

Comment: It seems that `.logic()` is called on another instance of the object than the one you are trying to retrieve the value from.

Comment: @Ghorich okey, so how can I call it on the same instance?

Comment: as @Ghorich noticed logic that is responsible for changing value is used in other class/instance. use this logic in this class B or make variable global (?)

Comment: @KurgerBing you can do so by passing this other instance as a variable into the scope of class B. For more information look into the basics of Object Oriented Programming (in Python) https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Comment: Anyway, A = A() is at least an anti-pattern: you hide the class behind an object of same name. Don't. Just don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `.logic()` is called on another instance of the object than the one you are trying to retrieve the value from. To retrieve the value from the same instance you can pass it as a variable in the scope of the other class. For more information look into the basics of [Object Oriented Programming (in Python)](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming)

Below I have written a small example of how this can be achieved:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.ev_nearby = 0

  def changeValue(self):
     self.ev_nearby = 1
     return self.ev_nearby

  # I want this value in class B
  def getChangedValue(self):
     return self.ev_nearby

  def logic(self):
      while(somethingHappens) {
         self.changeValue()
      }
  # logic is called in another class

class B:
  # I want the value here like
  def getValueFromA(self, A):
     valueFromA = A.getChangedValue()
     return valueFromA

class C:
  A = A()
  A.logic()
  B = B()
  B.getValueFromA(A)
```

Comment: I saw your answer a little late, but with the suggestions above I solved it exactly like that already! Now it works just fine. Thanks! :-)