# Use return value in Function A from function B in another class on call to function C

Tags: python

I have a couple of classes. A main class with a method `get_new_cert` which will call a method `update_cert` in a different class, but I need to pass the return value of a method `read_cert` from a third class (`VaultCert`).

My main function looks like this:

```
def get_new_cert(self, domain):
    print("Domain: " + domain)
    if domain == domain:
        print("Matches given domain variable - get_new_cert")
        UpdateCert(VaultCert(domain), self.list_certs(
            domain), VaultCert.key_data)
    else:
        print("something gone done broke - get_new_cert")
```

The method `read_cert` of `VaultCert` is:

```
def read_cert(self, domain):
    cert = client.secrets.kv.v1.read_secret(
        path='certs/' + domain + '/crt',
        mount_point='secret/'
    )
    print('The certificate is: {crt}'.format(
        crt=cert['data']['value'],
    ))

    key_data = client.secrets.kv.v1.read_secret(
        path='certs/' + domain + '/key',
        mount_point='secret/'
    )
    print('The key is: {key}'.format(
        key=key_data['data']['value'],
    ))

    chained_cert = client.secrets.kv.v1.read_secret(
        path='certs/' + domain + '/chained-crt',
        mount_point='secret/'
    )
    print('The chained cert is: {key}'.format(
        key=chained_cert['data']['value'],
    ))

    return cert, key_data, chained_cert
```

And the method `update_cert` that calls `VaultCert` as one of its parameters is:

```
def update_cert(self, cert, chained_cert, key, arn):
    try:
        response = client.import_certificate(
            CertificateArn=arn,
            Certificate=cert,
            PrivateKey=key,
            CertificateChain=chained_cert,
        )
        print("Cert imported")
    except ClientError as err:
        print(err)
    else:
        print("Cert not imported")
    response = client.get_certificate(
        CertificateArn=response["CertificateArn"])
    print(response)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A minimal working example of what you would like to accomplish would be nice;  there's too much irrelevant code here.

Comment: The question is how can I use the return value from read_cert in the update_cert method. These are in different classes

Comment: Did you define your classes in the same file?

Comment: No, the classes are defined in separate files, the classes are imported

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You use the return value like you use any other return value: by calling the method where you need it. Or by calling it somewhere else and passing the result along as a parameter.

Comment: Check this answer I think it would add something: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54106539/2114983

Comment: That works, but what if multiple things are being returned from a function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question is really how to use a tuple of return values from a function for further processing.

To achieve this, you can just assign the returned tuple like this:

```
cert, key_data, chained_cert = read_cert(domain)
```

and use it for calling the following function (adding a 4th parameter) like this:

```
update_cert(cert, chained_cert, key_data, arn)
```

Complete example with the functions in three different classes (using some dummy values):

```
class A:
  def get_new_cert(self, domain):
    # create new instances of both B and C
    b = B()
    c = C()
    # call read_cert in b
    cert, key_data, chained_cert = b.read_cert(domain)
    # call update_cert in c
    c.update_cert(cert, chained_cert, key_data, 'arn')

class B:
  def read_cert(self, domain):
    # return a tuple of dummy data
    return 'cert', 'key_data', 'chained_cert'

class C:
  def update_cert(self, cert, chained_cert, key, arn):
    print (cert, chained_cert, key, arn)

# call get_new_cert on a new instance of A
A().get_new_cert('Test')
```